React nativevictory-native XL Render Icons on X-axis and scroll bar chart horizontal
1.I am using https://commerce.nearform.com/open-source/victory-native/docs/cartesian/guides/basic-bar-chart
I would like to render svg icons instead of the x-axis label.
but I didn't find anything in the documentation. just accept string
enter image description here
formatXLabel dont works
2.How to scroll horizontally x-axis in the bar chart when my data overlaps the screen
Thanks

formatXLabel dont works to render anything else string


I can help with your second issue, I don't know if there is a better way, but I wrapped it inside a scrollView with a width corresponding with the data.
This way you can scroll horizontally

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
